# Crop/clip raster with shapefile that do not overlap

Tags: python, raster, clip, rasterio, earthpy

I have shapefile that intersects with a raster but do not fully overlap :

[image]

I would like to clip the raster with this shapefile but every time I try I  get this error message:

> ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.

I have tried two methods to clip the raster:
once with rasterio:

```
#get coordinates of shapefile
def getFeatures(gdf):
      """Function to parse features from GeoDataFrame in such a manner that rasterio wants them"""
       import json
       return [json.loads(gdf.to_json())['features'][0]['geometry']]

coords = getFeatures(plots)

out_img, out_transform = mask(img,coords, crop=True)
```

and once with earthpy:

```
crop=es.crop_image(img,plots)
```

both give me the same errors.

This is how I read the shape and the image:

```
#load shapefile
poly = geopandas.read_file(r'very\nice\path\and\polygon.shp')


#determine projection for shape and change it into the image projection
poly.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
poly=poly.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32721'})

#Load image
img=rasterio.open(r'what\a\wonderful\path\image.tif')
```

after this I used the methods that demonstrated.

How can I clip the raster with the polygon even if they are not the overlap 100%?

Edit:

I have tried this:

```
out_image, out_meta = es.crop_image(img, plots.geometry)
```

and also the same with rasterio as was suggested here but for some reason it clips only for the extent of the shape but not to the actual shape:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the solution (without a function like `def getFeatures(gdf`))

```
import rasterio 
out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(img, poly.geometry, crop=True)
```

[image][image]

Same with EarthPy

```
  out_image, out_meta = es.crop_image(img, poly.geometry)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have tried it but the results I get is clip to the polygon extent and not to the actual shape like in your image , do you have any idea why would it occur?

Comment: The result is  a clip of the original raster (coloured) to the polygon extent (grey raster)